# OnClientClick function not working in Edge browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net, microsoft-edge, onclientclick

I have a `LinkButton` control "Add to Bag" and when clicked I want to call a JavaScript function which adds `CSS` animation. It works on every other browser except Edge. I tried to research online if other people had this issue too, but I could not find anything. If I just call "alert('hello'); in OnClientClick it works. Has anyone had this issue and want can I do to fix it?

```asp
<asp:LinkButton ID="_addToCart" ToolTip="Add to Bag" runat="server" OnClick="AddToCart_Click" OnClientClick="return Pulse();"  ClientIDMode="Static" Text="Add to Bag"  />
```

```js
function Pulse() { 
    $('#totalItemBag').addClass("pulse2");
    $('#backgroundAnimation').addClass("backgroundChange");
}
```

```css
.pulse2 {
    animation: pulse2 1s linear infinite;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;*/ 
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

@keyframes pulse2 {
    0% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    25% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        -o-transform: scale(1.2);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
        background: url("../Images/icon-mybag-default.png") no-repeat;
        background-position: top;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50px;
    }
    50% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
        -o-transform: scale(1.4);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
        transform: scale(1.4);
        background: url("../Images/icon-mybag-default.png") no-repeat;
        background-position: top;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50px;
    }
    75% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
        -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
        -o-transform: scale(1.2);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
        transform: scale(1.2);
        background: url("../Images/icon-mybag-default.png") no-repeat;
        background-position: top;
        width: 50%;
        height: 50px;
    }
    100% {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1);
        -moz-transform: scale(1);
        -o-transform: scale(1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1);
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the CSS definitions for those classes, `pulse2` and `backgroundChange`? Its likely you are using rules that are not honored by Edge.

Comment: Nothing to do with Classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure this is linked to the */ forgotten token you have in your CSS.

[image]